# PHP / cURL or file_get_contents -- How to get the value of a JS page instead of the JS code

Tags: javascript, php

This is hopefully an easy question, but it's giving me an issue. I have a page "sample.html" with a simple script like this in JS:

```
// sample.html
<script>
    let myNumber = 15;
    document.write(myNumber);
</script>
```

... and then I want to have a PHP page ("getValue.php") go and get that number (e.g., 15). My problem is:  If I do a file_get_contents or even a cURL to that JS page, like so...

```
// getValue.php
$newVal = file_get_contents('sample.html');
```

... the $newVal var in PHP is NOT simply the "15" value. Instead, the var is equal to the entire JS script shown. So, how can I use PHP to get that "15" value alone as a variable?   In other words, I only want $newVar to be the *result* of the JS page, not the entire script. What I want to achieve is:

// $newVal == 15

Comment: You would need to _execute_ the JS code, which you can not do (directly) in PHP. You'd need to either submit the code to a JS engine or alternatively (if your real-world use case is as simple as this example) you might be able to just parse out the text of the value you need.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

With file_get_content you cant do that.

You looking for a php scrapper of JavaScript genertaed content. One tool would be PHP-Webdriver. It base on Selenium.

https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver